# "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

I am trying to learn D3.js javascript library. When I try to run the below code I get "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error. Source file and the file I am trying to load (bolliger-mabillard.csv) are both in same folder. I am running it on Mac using Google Chrome. How do I force Chrome to load this csv file ?

```
function init() {

    d3.csv("http://localhost/~vikalpjain/bolliger-mabillard.csv",function(data){
        vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform","translate(0," + (h-MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

        vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class" ,"y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

        update ();
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running your example on your own server try to replace *`localhost`* by *`127.0.0.1`*, this is because the domain name has to be exactly the same to the server you are querying.